# How do i modify the object of a method?

Tags: java

This is my code:

```java
     public class Combination {
        private int[] code;


        // Constructor
        public Combination( int first, int second, int third ) {
          code[0] = first;
          code[1] = second;
          code[2] = third;

        }

        public boolean equals( Combination other ) {
          if (other.code == ){
            return true;
          } else{
            return false;
          }
        }

        public String toString() {
          String temp = ( (toString)() +":"+ (toString)() +":"+ (toString)() );
          return temp;
        }

    }
```

`Combination` is a class that we create.  If I were to use a line like `c1.equals(c2)` by example how would I modify and/or access the `c1` variable in the method equals. (`c2` is easy since I just use other)
same thing to `toString`

I have no idea how to use a method while using `x.method(y)`
I have used `method(y)` but never used a `x.method()`
while compiling the only errors are that there is things missing (voluntarily)

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here: if (other.code == ){

Comment: `c1` would be `this` in your example, So the line would be `this.code[0]== other.code[0]`

Comment: Do note that `public boolean equals(Combination other)` does **not** override equals from Object (it's unclear if this is intended). Also note that your constructor will throw NullPointerException.

Comment: Before posting here, study *The Java Tutorials* by Oracle Corp, free of cost. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x.method(y)` simply means that you use a method of a specific instance of a class, that imply using specific data and behavior

let's make an example:

```
public class Pojo {

    public final String text;

    public Pojo(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }


    public void print(){
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

if you create a new Pojo and invoke its `print` method the printed
text may be different for each Pojo.

```
Pojo pojo1 = new Pojo("Text-1");
pojo1.print();
```

will print 'Text-1' in console, instead

```
Pojo pojo2 = new Pojo("Text-Different");
pojo2.print();
```

will print 'Text-Different' in console.

Comment: oh ok! so i just refer to pojo1 as text, the variable it alrady contain! okokok thanks a lot i think i understand now thanks! (im not sure why im at -2 on the question but yeah sure)